# Is there any way of using JSX in a native CommonJS environment?

Tags: commonjs, reactjs, electron

I'm starting a new project on an environment that has native **CommonJS** support for `require` modules - *it's an atom-shell project, there is no possibility of using pre-compiling steps such as in Browserify or webpack AFAIK*.

I'm able to use JSX on my `app.jsx` entry-point file that is declared on my `index.html`, that's because `JSXTransformer` was declared previously:

```html
<script src="scripts/vendor/JSXTransformer.js"></script>
<script type="text/jsx" src="scripts/app.jsx"></script>
```

I want to be able to use the JSX syntax for the sub modules that are imported as CommonJS modules inside my `app.jsx` module:

```js
// This raises an Error, the XML-like tags are not supported
var Grid = require('./scripts/grid.jsx');
```

As far as I understand, I would be forced to drop the JSX syntax and go with the vanilla syntax for any module that is loaded via `require`. Are there any alternatives to still using JSX in this situation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**[Update]**

Now that the JSX transformer [is being deprecated in favor of Babel](http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/06/12/deprecating-jstransform-and-react-tools.html), you can use Babel's [require hook](http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/require/) to support JSX in CommonJS-like environments:

> ### Usage
>
> ```javascript
> require("babel/register");
> ```
>
> All subsequent files required by node with the extensions `.es6`, `.es`, `.jsx` and `.js` will be transformed by Babel. The [polyfill](http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill) is also automatically required.
>
> **NOTE:** By default all requires to `node_modules` will be ignored. You can override this by passing an ignore regex via:
>
> ```javascript
> require("babel/register")({
>   // This will override `node_modules` ignoring - you can alternatively pass
>   // an array of strings to be explicitly matched or a regex / glob
>   ignore: false
> });
> ```

**[Old Answer]**

If it's a Node.js environment (like atom-shell is) you can use [node-jsx](https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-jsx):

```javascript
require('node-jsx').install()
require("./myComponent.js");
```

You can also use the `.jsx` extension if you want:

```javascript
require('node-jsx').install({extension: '.jsx'})
require("./myComponent.jsx");
```

Comment: The line `require('babel/register')` has since changed to `require('babel-register')` - https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babel-register/

Answer (score 1):

You can simply copy over the source directory:

```
cp -R src dist
```

And then use the jsx tool from [react-tools](https://www.npmjs.org/package/react-tools)

```
jsx -x jsx dist dist
```

And remove the jsx files

```
find dist -iname '*.jsx' | xargs rm
```

---

There are perhaps cleaner ways to do this, but this should be good enough for now.