# How can we use react jsx templates in node-webkit

Tags: reactjs, gulp, node-webkit, nw.js

I'm having troubles using react's `jsx`templates in node-webkit. The basic problem boils down to this; Using the following code

```
React.createClass({
    render:function(){
        return <h1>Hello FLUX</h1>
    }
});
```

will have node-webkit telling me

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

I have been searching and did not find a satisfying solution. The best thing I came up with, is compiling the jsx-based files to proper js and storing them in a separate directory (using gulp). But this solution annoys me for it means requiring files that are technically not *there*.

What other solutions are there?

Comment: See this similar question about Atom Shell here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26743434/62082

Answer (score 2):

You can use [node-jsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-jsx) to require `.jsx` files and parse them appropriately.

Most simply, you require and install like so:

`require('node-jsx').install({extension: '.jsx'})`

and then any future files you require with a `.jsx` extension will be parsed.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot load JSX files as you load regular JS files. The problem here is that your JSX file is interpreted as a standard JS file. Make sure that in your DOM you load your file like this (pay attention to `text/jsx`)

```
<script type="text/jsx" src="yourscript.js"></script>
```

And that in your HEAD you also loaded first React **and** the JSXTransformer so that the transformations can occur in the browser.

Source : [React's Getting started](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/getting-started.html)

Comment: I would like to make use of `require` to load JavaScript/JSX files. Otherwise I would end up with an unmaintainable list of script tags. Any way you see I can do that? Browserify sure would help, but that would mess with node's native `require`.

Comment: You can define multiple React classes in a single file, you do not need to create one per file, that's okay. What you can do, is use require.js or something [like jsx-requirejs](https://github.com/philix/jsx-requirejs-plugin) so that in development it loads the files separately but for production using r.js all jsx files are minified into one.

Comment: You're fundamentally misunderstanding the question here -- Lukas wants to use require from node, which means on the server side, not in the browser.